# Show that $k$-colorings of a link are in bijection with homomorphism $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus L)\to D_k$

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

Here $D_k$ is the group of symmetries of a regular $k$-gon. $D_k$ has $2k$ elements, the $k$ rotations through multiples of $2\pi/k$ and the $k$ reflections.

I think this is related to Wirtinger presentation of knot groups, which says that if a link $L$ has strands $a_1, ..., a_n$ and the relations associated to its crossings are $r_1, ..., r_m$, then 
$$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus L)\cong\langle a_1,...a_n|\ r_1, ..., r_m\rangle.$$

I have been getting criticism for not showing any effort, the problem is I really don't know what's going on so I am asking here on mse.

Comment: Since there's a latex error I have made an edit. Please take a look and see if that is what you want.

Comment: This was discovered by Fox. The story is told, and the bijection is explained, in brief language at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_n-coloring. See the references at the bottom of the web page for more details.